# xcalib unable to read file ''

Tags: bash, shell

When trying to use the xcalib tool to adjust the screens color and resolution such as...

```
xcalib -red 1.1 10.0 100.0
```

I get the error

```
Warning - Unable to read file ''
```

The error started after adding the xorg .conf file

```
Section "Device"
   Identifier "Intel Graphics"
   Driver "intel"
EndSection
```

before adding this I was getting an error

```
Error-unsupported ramp size 0
```

Comment: `Last parameter MUST be an ICC profile containing a vcgt or mLUT tag or empty if the "-a" or "-alter" paramter is used or the LUT is to be cleared.` Source: `man xcalib`

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
xcalib -red 1.1 10.0 100.0 -a
```

Comment: What does the ```-a``` mean? Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.